# While shrinking synchronized blocks can improve scalability, a synchronized block can be too small. Shouldn't "can" be "can not"?

Tags: java, synchronized

I am reading *Java Concurrency in Practice* and encounter the following snippet.

> While shrinking synchronized blocks can improve scalability, a synchronized block **can** be too small—operations that need to be atomic (such updating multiple variables that participate in an invariant) must be contained in a single synchronized block.

Is there a typo? Shouldn't "can" be "can not"?

Answer (score 3):

No, it is correct, if you have a sequence of operations that are atomic, which means they must be done together as if they were just a single operation, then the synchronized block must include the whole sequence.